# Monotouch: Playing MP3 user control

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, mp3, avplayer

Using Monotouch I can play an MP3:

```
avPlayer = MonoTouch.AVFoundation.AVPlayer.FromUrl(new NSUrl("http://blah.mp3"));

avPlayer.Play();
```

Is there a Monotouch control that I can display to the user to give them a pause/stop scan functionality?

Before I write my own I wanted to make sure I'm not doing so for no reason.

Ian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the [AVTouch](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/tree/master/AVTouchSample) sample (adapted from Apple's sample) has UI controls.